# What does it mean for $x$ to be not upper bounded by any polynomial in $y$?

Tags: polynomials

I am reading a statement saying the value $2^n-3$ is not upper bounded by any polynomial in $|S|$ where $|S|=n \cdot \binom{n}{2}$. I am just trying to understand the intuition behind this.

My understanding is the following: a polynomial in $|S|$ has the form $x^{|S|}$ for some fixed $x$. But I fail to see how the statement is true if $x=2. $

Comment: It appears to be referring to the fact that if $P$ is a polynomial there exists $n$ such that $2^n-3>P(n).$  What "polynomial in $|S|$ where $|S|=n\binom {n}{2} $" means, I dk.

Comment: A polynomial in $|S|$ is like $|S|^x$, not $x^{|S|}$

Comment: @EricWofsey thanks. then that seems true as $|S|^{x}$ wont upper bound $2^{n}-3$

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial in $|S|$ is a function of the form $c_0 + c_1 |S| + \dots + c_k |S|^k$ for constants $c_0,c_1,\dots,c_k$. In your case such a function behaves, for large $n$, like $n^{3k}$. But $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{n^{3k}}=\infty$ for any $k$.